# Is there a way to change my hostname to fix "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known."?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, composer-php, mariadb

I'm trying to connect to a MariaDB SQL database but am unsure how to phrase my hostname (which doesn't look like a URL at all). My database hosting service tells me that my hostname is `spike-codes-db-19d5bab155-mariadb` yet when I try this along with other variants (see below), I get an error telling me that `No such host is known.`

My PHP script is hosted from Heroku but the error logging below was from my localhost testing server. The SQL database is MariaDB and hosted by unubo.com and I know everything is fine with it.

What I've tried for the hostname:

- spike-codes-db-19d5bab155-mariadb
- spike-codes-db-19d5bab155-mariadb:3306
- spike-codes-db-19d5bab155-mariadb-master-0
- mariadb://[user]:[password]@spike-codes-db-19d5bab155-mariadb:3306

**Brackets are used for redacted data.**

Please don't flag this as a duplicate, I've checked all the other questions with that return the same error code and none of which fix my issue (most explain how to fix the syntax but I'm unsure about my hostname, which none of those other questions cover, all using 'localhost' as the server name).

```php
<?php

$hostname = "spike-codes-db-19d5bab155-mariadb";
$username = get_env("db_user");
$password = get_env("db_pass");
$db = get_env("db_name");

$conn=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$db);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM reviews";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Expected: Returned DB information.

Error message:

````
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in [file_location] on line 8
Connection failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
opcache_reset();
?>
```

I have the same problem. I tried many solutions, none of them works. This one is work for me.
You need to reset Opcache on CLI. Create a file using the above code.eg.. clear.php
And run it. Then try again to run your original code. It will solve the issue.

Comment: Sadly this didn't seem to help as for me, Opchache is an undefined function, your solution may be specific to some other hosting platform.